# newCachedThreadPool with ThreadFactory

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, java-7

I am implement a thread pool for my application and I want to use newCachedThreadPool along with ThreadFactory, and I wonder what I wrote below is correct.

1.The idea of using newCachedThreadPool is that thread can be reusable, and that idle thread will be terminated appropriately like the jdk7 doc provided. However, when I wrote the code, I have some doubt since in `newThread(Runnable r)`, I return new instance of `MyThread`, and I also does `MyThread myThread = new MyThread();` in `main`. So please if an experienced developers can point out whether what I did below are correct or not, I would greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;

public class ThreadFactoryTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService cachedPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new MyThreadFactory());
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        cachedPool.submit(myThread);
    }        
}

class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory{
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new MyThread(r);
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {

    public MyThread(Runnable r){
        super(r);
    }

    public MyThread(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        if(t instanceof MyThread){
            System.out.println("Thread is MyThread");
        }
        System.out.println("Inside: " + this.getName());
        Utils.awesome();
    }
}

class Utils{
    public static void awesome(){
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        if(t instanceof MyThread){
            System.out.println("Inside awesome() and Thread is MyThread. Provide special awesomeness for MyThread.");
        }            
    }    
}
```

When I run the above program it produces

```
Thread is MyThread
Inside: Thread-1
Inside awesome() and Thread is MyThread. Provide special awesomeness for MyThread.
```

which are the correct outputs, what I am asking is whether I am setting up correctly.

Comment: You never run your runnable in MyThread's run...

Comment: @assylias: can u elaborate please? My threading knowledge is quite limited

Comment: You never call `r.run()`

Comment: @assylias: I thought `cachedPool.submit(myThread);` does that, is it not?

Comment: No, Thread.run() does - but you never call `super.run()` here...

Comment: @assylias: Please see my update in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should *not* submit a `Thread` to the `ExecutorService#submit(Runnable)` method. Although `Thread` implements the `Runnable` interface, this is rather an artifact ( [Why does Thread implement Runnable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305953/why-does-thread-implement-runnable) ).

In general, you submit *tasks* to the `ExecutorService`. And these tasks are descriptions about **what** has to be done, regardles of **which thread** will do it. The management of worker threads is completely left to the `ExecutorService` implementation (and the `ThreadFactory` that it is using internally).

At least one can say that

```
if(this instanceof MyThread){
    System.out.println("Thread is MyThread");
}
```

does not make sense, because the `instanceof` test will always be true. Maybe you wanted to test something like

```
if(Thread.currentThread() instanceof MyThread) {
    System.out.println("This runnable is executed by a Thread that is a MyThread");
}
```

But since you're setting an appropriate `ThreadFactory`, this message will always be printed

So depending on what your "awesomeness" should be, this could be done either in a special implementation of `Runnable`, or in your special `MyThread` class. More precisely: The appropriate solution will depend on whether this "awesome stuff" should be related to the *tasks* that are executed, or to the *threads* that are executing the tasks.

In any case, you should also consider to manually create an instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` where you override the [beforeExecute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute-java.lang.Thread-java.lang.Runnable-) or [afterExecute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.Throwable-) method in order to do awesome things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the reason I check for `t instanceof MyThread` is because there are different types of thread. For example now, i just `return MyThread(r)`, but what I want is to pull out some type of information of `Runnable r`, so that I can decide what thread to create, however, `r` is type `ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker`, so I dont know how. Do you have a solution for this Marco?

Comment: Yes, the `Worker` class does some internal bookkeeping. However, there is a pool of threads, and usually it should not matter which thread executes which task. Maybe you should describe on a higher abstraction level what you *actually* want to achieve...