# I am trying to call thread 2 from thread 1 (for five times in a loop), but thread 2 starts executing only after the loop in thread 1 is complete

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a 2 threads defined in an android activity. Both threads are created as runnable instances. Thread 1 is a runnable object called "timer1" (created using an anonymous inner class) and Thread 2(assigned to runnable object "timer2") is invoked from Thread 1 using Thread 2's handler (using the post() method).

Thread 2's handler is called "tempHandler" (it is an instance variable) and is initialized in the constructor of the "MyRunnable" class.

Thread1 makes 5 calls to Thread2 in a for loop. The intended outcome is that Thread2 should run each time a post() call is made to it. But it does not happen. Instead the entire loop in Thread1 completes and only then does Thread2 run. Why does this happen? And how to rectify it?

This is the 1st thread:

```
timer1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timer2 = new MyRunnable();

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                tempHandler.post(timer2);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }
    };
```

This is the 2nd thread:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    public MyRunnable() {
        tempHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(Looper.myLooper() == null) {
            Looper.prepare();
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;

        System.out.println("Array traversal time: " + String.valueOf(elapsedTime));
        System.out.println("Exited thread 2");

        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you're populating the result in UI, right ?

Comment: In general, you don't _call_ threads. Your code does not show any reference to threads. The timing statements in `MyRunnable#run` don't make sense to me.

Comment: no, I do not wany any change to the ui

Comment: Ralf H: the timing statements are just random statements.. I did not want to add all my code so I just added a snippet.. It just calcluates the time taken..

Comment: why you're not putting the second snippet in the first thread instead of making it separate

Comment: Hard to guess.  You have not shown us _any_ code that creates or start()s any Thread object.  How do we know you are using threads at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown the code that starts the threads, but it sounds like maybe you're assuming [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)s are [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)s. They're not.

A `Runnable` is just that: a thing you can run by calling its `run()` method. But it runs in the same thread you call it from.

An example to see what I'm talking about:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(mainThread);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
            System.out.println(mainThread == Thread.currentThread());
        }
    };
    r.run();
}
```

The output is something like:

```
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[main,5,main]
true
```

You create a separate thread which will run the `Runnable` by calling [`new Thread(r)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.Runnable-). Replacing the line `r.run();` in the above example with:

```
    Thread newThread = new Thread(r);
    newThread.start();
```

The output becomes:

```
Thread[main,5,]
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
false
```

Success – we have two different threads!

Note: make certain you are calling [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) on your `Thread` objects, and not [`run()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run--). That's the other possible reason your code isn't working. Although `Thread` objects have a public `run()` method, this is a historical mistake in Java; [you should never call it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305953/why-does-thread-implement-runnable), because that just runs the code on the current thread without starting a new one.

Comment: Yes, I agree that a Runnable by itself is not a thread. But the code snippet that I had posted above was a part of an android code, and many examples have said that we can indeed use a Runnable as a way to create new background threads in android. Is that not true ?

Comment: You can create a Thread from a Runnable. A Runnable on its own is not a thread, whether it is in Android or not.

Comment: oh I misunderstood then.. sorry :(

Comment: Thank you. I had a wrong understanding all this time and now I'm clear. But this leads me to another doubt. Could you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129682/how-to-ensure-synchronization-when-one-thread-keeps-sending-data-to-another-thre