# How to ensure synchronization when one thread keeps sending data to another thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

There are 2 threads: Thread1 and Thread2, in addition to the main UI thread.

The UI thread spawns Thread1. Thread1 spwans Thread2 and keeps sending an array to Thread2 at periodic intervals.

Thread2 should keep listening to Thread1 and whenever it receives data, Thread2 will process it and send the result back to the UI thread.

How can this be achieved? I started off using handlers but did not know how to send Thread2's handler to Thread1, so that Thread1 can keep posting data to Thread2's message queue.

This is Thread1:

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
Handler handler;
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

@Override
public void run() {

    Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2();
    thread2.start();
    handler = thread2.getHandler();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        thread2.passData(a);
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is Thread2:

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread {
private int a[];
Handler handler;

public void passData(int a[]) {
    this.a = new int[10];
    this.a = a.clone();
}

public Handler getHandler() {
    return handler;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if(Looper.myLooper() == null) {
        Looper.prepare();
    }

    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                //random work
            }
        }
    };
    Looper.loop();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show some code? I don't know why it should **not** be possible to retrieve Thread2's handler from Thread1?

Comment: not enought informations. What kind of data? what kind of process?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you need a good performance but one simple way to achieve is to use this object
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: This is the best approach I think, but I don't know why you're implying BlockingQueues are slow; they're not.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Thread1 and Thread2 are a both `HandlerThread`s, they can can just send messages to each other using each other's `Handler`(s).

> I started off using handlers but did not know how to send Thread2's handler to Thread1, so that Thread1 can keep posting data to Thread2's message queue.

Specific to this question, you can either create a method on HandlerThread2 that wraps the handler.post() and call that from HandlerThread1's reference to HandlerThread2.

```
//in HandlerThread2
public void send(SomeData data) {
    this.handler.post([runnable]);
}
```

Or you can provide an accessor in HandlerThread2 to get the actual handler from HandlerThread2 and use it directly.

```
//in HandlerThread2
public Handler getHandler() {
    return this.handler;
}
```

Comment: I added my code. There is a chance that a null pointer may be returned when I call getHandler() from Thread1

Comment: You should subclass `HandlerThread` instead of Thread.  This helps to ensure things get set up correctly.  Specifically the `onLooperPrepared` method is where you should create your handler.  And from Thread1 you can call `getLooper()` to ensure it's been initialized before continuing.